# Iterating through table to use as parameters in function to create large new table

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, iteration

I have been researching this and haven't found a usable answer yet. I'm a moderate hack with SQL Server and have some success with using parameters in functions and stored procedures but this is a combination that I can't seem to get my head around.

Here is my scenario summarized for clarity:
My company sells computers as laptops and desktops and accessories. I have a tbl_Computers where I maintain Computer_Type, Model_Num, and Mix_Percent like this:

```
Desktop  ABC  .75  
Desktop  XYZ  .25  
Laptop   DEF  .60  
Laptop   MNO  .40
```

We also have a table for forecast by month where I maintain Computer_Type, Jul_Num, Aug_Num, and Sep_Num like this:

```
Desktop  100  200  150  
Laptop   300  400  700
```

I have created a function for a planning bill of material that will find all components and accessories sold in the past twelve months for a given model. It works as follows:
P_BOM ("ABC") will result in a table with two columns: Component and Comp_Percent

```
CPU        1  (This means we sell 1 CPU with every desktop)  
Hard Drive 2  (We sell 2 with every desktop)  
Printer    .8 (80% of the time we sell a printer)
```

What I'd like my Stored Procedure to do is to provide a single, combined table that would look like this with the following headers Component, Jul_Num, Aug_Num, and Sep_Num:

```
CPU         400  600  850  
Hard Drive  500  800  1000
```

I get the CPU number by summing the following logic:
Desktop's Jul_Num x ABC's Mix_Percentage x ABC's CPU Comp_Percent
Desktop's Jul_Num x XYZ's Mix_Percentage x XYZ's CPU Comp_Percent
Laptop's Jul_Num x ABC's Mix_Percentage x ABC's CPU Comp_Percent
Laptop's Jul_Num x XYZ's Mix_Percentage x XYZ's CPU Comp_Percent
400 = (100 x .75 x 1) + (100 x .25 x 1) + (300 x .6 x 1) + (300 x .4 x 1)

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rob

EDIT:

Thanks to the suggestion that this needn't be an iterative problem but rather a table-based solution.

I created this first table to give me:

```
ABC CPU          3  3   1
ABC Hard Drive   6  3   2
DEF CPU          2  2   1
DEF Hard Drive   2  2   1
MNO CPU          1  1   1
MNO Hard Drive   1  1   1
XYZ CPU          1  1   1
XYZ Hard Drive   2  1   2
```

Here was the SQL:

```
SELECT        All_Components.Model_Num, All_Components.Part_Num, SUM(All_Components.Qty) AS Total, TTO.Target_Total, SUM(All_Components.Qty) 
                     / TTO.Target_Total AS Comp_Percent
FROM            (SELECT        Test_tbl_Computers.Model_Num, Test_tbl_Orders_2.Order_Num, Test_tbl_Orders_2.Part_Num, Test_tbl_Orders_2.Qty
                      FROM            Test_tbl_Orders AS Test_tbl_Orders_2 CROSS JOIN
                                                Test_tbl_Computers) AS All_Components INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT        Test_tbl_Orders.Part_Num, SUM(Test_tbl_Orders.Qty) AS Target_Total
                           FROM            Test_tbl_Orders INNER JOIN
                                                     Test_tbl_Computers AS Test_tbl_Computers_1 ON Test_tbl_Orders.Part_Num = Test_tbl_Computers_1.Model_Num
                           GROUP BY Test_tbl_Orders.Part_Num) AS TTO ON All_Components.Model_Num = TTO.Part_Num
WHERE        (All_Components.Order_Num IN
                         (SELECT        Order_Num
                           FROM            Test_tbl_Orders AS Test_tbl_Orders_1
                           WHERE        (Part_Num = All_Components.Model_Num))) AND (All_Components.Part_Num <> All_Components.Model_Num)
```

Then, to keep it from becoming a SQL-Monster I couldn't tame, I created another function to conduct an inner join to the forecast and mix percentages and then sum up all numbers grouping by Part_Num.

If nothing else, I appreciated having to write out my question to help focus my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why do you need a function here. All the data you are stating here can be stored in tables and then picked up with simple joins.
Even if the BOM is recursive you can make use of CTEs.

If you insist using the function you can use `CROSS APPLY` to call the function to each row.

---

> The only function I've created thus far has been to create a
>   two-column table filled with all components sold on the same sales
>   order as a specific desktop model. Are you recommending that I post
>   the results of that table to another table and continue to insert new
>   rows for each instance of the function?

I see, you don't need to use a function.
there are many different possibilities,

one that you are probably very close to it, is converting the function to a SP and use the

```
INSERT INTO [TableName]
EXEC [SP_NAME]
```

another one convert the query into an accumulating subquery or CTE (see below) 
and join it with the others.

**in general avoid creating functions every time you can, because they make big damage to the database.**

> The BOM's are not recursive. I'm not familiar with CTE's.

Common Table Expression (CTE) are great tools when you have many concatenated subqueries, once you get used to them, they bring lot of clarity (IMO) to complex queries. 
CTEs also provide native support for recursion. 
There are tons of articles in the net that will guide you. just google CTE expamples or CTE tutorials

> I have no experience with CROSS APPLY.

CROSS APPLY: from page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for each row returned by an outer table expression of a query.

last and not least

> Any examples would be appreciated

if you would give me the partial scripts that you already had, I'll try convert it to the query that I meant to guide you.

Comment: The only function I've created thus far has been to create a two-column table filled with all components sold on the same sales order as a specific desktop model. Are you recommending that I post the results of that table to another table and continue to insert new rows for each instance of the function?

The BOM's are not recursive.

I'm not familiar with CTE's.

I have no experience with CROSS APPLY.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @user2547072, you are asking too many questions for just a comment, please see my extended edited answer.

Comment: Luis, Thanks for pointing me to CTE's!!! I appreciate more-readable code whenever I can find it. You've changed my programming style!

Comment: @user2547072  I would appreciate if you mark my response as Accepted? I'm starting to participate in Stackoverflow right now, I see that the gained points have impact on how I can participate

Answer (score 1):

"Computer_Type, Jul_Num, Aug_Num, and Sep_Num"

One-column-per-month works for reporting or a data-entry interface, but you are going to drive yourself absolutely bonkers if you actually store the data that way.  If you have the means to go back and change that table to "Computer_Type, Year, Month, Num" or "Computer_Type, Date, Num", then you should do that *first*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, how would you create an ASP.net GridView for data entry using your format? I want to be able to display and edit according to the Computer_Type, Jul_Num, Aug_Num, and Sep_Num convention with all numbers in a single row for "Desktop".  Currently, I'm adding a new ItemTemplate for each column explicitly labeled for Jul_Num, etc.